# How can I change a variable with a bash script in another bash script?

Tags: bash

Both Bash scripts are located in the same folder on a server. It should be possible to change the START and STOP variables so that the For loop in Direx.sh always works in steps of 10. My problem is that I honestly have little idea about Bash.
Bash Script with Loop. I will call it Direx:

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
./Direx_Opener.sh $START $END
for (( i=$START; i<=$END; i++))
do
.
.
.
done
wait
```

Second bash script to change the START and STOP variable. I will call it Direx_Opener.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((j=0; j<11; j++))
do 
for((a=1, b=10; a<=b; a++))
do
source  Direx.sh $START $END
done
$START=$(($a+10))
$END ="$(($b+10)) 
done
```

Comment: Why not simply use one script and loop, e.g. `for ((a = 1; a <= final; a += 10))` and increment by 10 each time? There isn't any reason to use two scripts and source on in the other for this case. You can sill nest the 2nd loop with, e.g. `for ((b = a; b < 10; b++))` and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's a good idea, I may have misunderstood the person I was talking to because I wasn't speaking to them in my mother tongue.

Comment: Don't use `source`; assuming that `Direx.sh` is in your PATH, just invoke it as `Direx.sh $START $END`. The main problem (asside from the syntax errors in setting `START` and `END` - they are likely typos - seems to me that you try to **use** the variables `START` and `END` before you set them. To catch this type of error, put a `set -u` at the start of your scripts.

Comment: Check your syntax via https://www.shellcheck.net/